# How to extract specific data from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extract

I have a variable created in leaflet and I need to extract a part of inside data that are gps coordinates, in order to use separately
This is my var and how it is generatared

var track = new L.GPX('tracce_gpx/Subit(via Porzûs)_Attimis.gpx', {async: true,   display_wpt:false,  color: '#a539a8',opacity:0.6,weight:6}).addTo(Video);

with "console.log(track);"

in browser console I obtain:

```
i {options: {…}, _gpx: 'tracce_gpx/Subit(via Porzûs)_Attimis.gpx', _layers: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true, _events: {…}, …}
options:{async: true, display_wpt: false, color: '#a539a8', opacity: 0.6, weight: 6}
_events:{click: Array(1)}
_gpx:"tracce_gpx/Subit(via Porzûs)_Attimis.gpx"
_initHooksCalled:true
_layers:126:i
options:{async: true, display_wpt: false, color: '#a539a8', opacity: 0.6, weight: 6}
_bounds:R {_southWest: D, _northEast: D}
_eventParents:{125: i}
_events:{click: Array(1), keypress: Array(1), remove: Array(1), move: Array(1)}
_initHooksCalled:true
_latlngs:Array(588)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 299]
[300 … 399]
[400 … 499]
[500 … 587]
length:588
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
_leaflet_id: 126
_popup:i {options: {…}, _source: i, _initHooksCalled: true, _content: '<p>12.0 km</p>'}
_popupHandlersAdded:true
 [[Prototype]]:i
 [[Prototype]]:Object
_leaflet_id:125
[[Prototype]]:i
```

[image]

What a need is to extract and assign data from (_latlngs : ) to a new variable
this is a part of a more complicated question posted here:

[How to create leaflet polyline, after loading Gpx track, with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76598233/how-to-create-leaflet-polyline-after-loading-gpx-track-with-different-colors)

thanks for any suggestion

Further on: after various readings and tries, probably what I thougt was an Array, in reality was an object or a pseudo-array

```
for(key in track) {
if(track.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = track[key];
    console.log(value);
    //do something with value;
}
```

}

I obtain following console answer:

```
    {async: true, display_wpt: false, color: '#a539a8', opacity: 0.6, weight: 6}
tracce_gpx/Subit(via Porzûs)_Attimis.gpx
{}
 126: 
  ioptions: {async: true, display_wpt: false, color: '#a539a8', 
             opacity: 0.6, weight: 6}
  _bounds: R {_southWest: D, _northEast: D}_eventParents: {125: i}
  _events: {click: Array(1), keypress: Array(1), remove: Array(1), 
            move: Array(1)}
  _initHooksCalled: true
  _latlngs: Array(588)[0 … 99][100 … 199][200 … 299][300 … 399][400 … 
                    499][500 … 587]length: 588[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
  _leaflet_id: 368
  _popup: i {options: {…}, 
  _source: i, 
  _initHooksCalled: true, _content: '<p>12.0 km</p>'}
  _popupHandlersAdded: true[[Prototype]]: i[[Prototype]]: Object true
{click: Array(1)}
125
```

using

```
 var nuova = track._layers;
     console.log(nuova);
```

I obtain what is inside _layers

```
{}
 126:i
  options:{async: true, display_wpt: false, color: '#a539a8', opacity: 0.6, weight: 6}
  _bounds:R {_southWest: D, _northEast: D}
  _eventParents:{85: i}
  _events:{click: Array(1), keypress: Array(1), remove: Array(1), move: Array(1)}
  _initHooksCalled:true
  _latlngs:(588) [D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, …]
  _leaflet_id:328
  _popup:i {options: {…}, _source: i, _initHooksCalled: true, _content: '<p>12.0 km</p>'}
  _popupHandlersAdded:true
  [[Prototype]]:i
 [[Prototype]]:Object
```

I tryed to extract specific data of _latlngs: using

```
console.log(nuova._latlngs);
```

I get undefined and can't arrange to extract data.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` to get a more presentable print out of the structure of your data at the time of the logging.

Comment: It looks like the path to it has the object named `126` in there, so you would need to call `nuova['126']._latlngs`

Comment: Also, be careful when editing; you removed a number of changes I made to fix misspellings that I don't feel like doing again.

Comment: when I use "console.log(nuova['126']._latlngs);" I obtain "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_latlngs')"

Comment: sorry Heretic Monkey, for causing problems, I was trying to keep output more visually correct.

Comment: when I use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` I get only `{}`, and when I use `console.log(nuova['126'])`; I get "undefined"